# How to get $_SESSION value in the next php page with facebook sdk?

Tags: php, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api

I'm using facebook SDK login latest version php [Facebook sdk I'm using](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_batch_request)

Login facebook and redirection page is correct, but my problem is that I can get `$_SESSION['fb_access_token']` in the second php file to get and show the name, email...

THe code is from the web page:

login.php

```
 session_start();
 require_once( 'Facebook/autoload.php' );

  $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app-id}',
  'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
 ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$permissions = ['email']; // Optional permissions
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://example.com/fb-callback.php',    $permissions);

  echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
```

fb-callback.php

```
 session_start();
 $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
'app_id' => '{app-id}',
'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
]);

 $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

 try {
   $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
 echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

 if (! isset($accessToken)) {
   if ($helper->getError()) {
     header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
     echo "Error: " . $helper->getError() . "\n";
    echo "Error Code: " . $helper->getErrorCode() . "\n";
    echo "Error Reason: " . $helper->getErrorReason() . "\n";
    echo "Error Description: " . $helper->getErrorDescription() . "\n";
  } else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
    echo 'Bad request';
    }
   exit;
}

// Logged in
echo '<h3>Access Token</h3>';
 var_dump($accessToken->getValue());

 // The OAuth 2.0 client handler helps us manage access tokens
 $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

 // Get the access token metadata from /debug_token
 $tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);
 echo '<h3>Metadata</h3>';
 var_dump($tokenMetadata);

 // Validation (these will throw FacebookSDKException's when they fail)
 $tokenMetadata->validateAppId($config['app_id']);
 // If you know the user ID this access token belongs to, you can validate it     here
 //$tokenMetadata->validateUserId('123');
 $tokenMetadata->validateExpiration();

 if (! $accessToken->isLongLived()) {
    // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
  try {
    $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
  } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
     echo "<p>Error getting long-lived access token: " . $helper->getMessage() . "</p>\n\n";
   exit;
  }

   echo '<h3>Long-lived</h3>';
   var_dump($accessToken->getValue());
 }

 $_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

// User is logged in with a long-lived access token.
 // You can redirect them to a members-only page.
 //header('Location: https://example.com/members.php');
```

In the second php file  `$_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken`; is declared, but when I call this in the next view I'cant load this because show undeclared or empty variable. I 'm beginner php but I used the next code to load session, to call php api..:

```
 <?php
  session_start();

 require_once( 'Facebook/autoload.php' );
 require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
 require_once( 'Facebook/Helpers/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );

 use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
 use Facebook\Helpers\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

 echo $_SESSION['fb_access_token'];
```

I'm showing a lot of tutorials, examples, but never use the actual api php login or use javascript.

How can do this with the php login facebook code and show email, name and other in a page then login?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: did you start the session? `session_start()`

Comment: yes, I have session_start(); line in both all files.

Comment: after you set the session, try printing it using `print_r()` just to see what's actually in there

Comment: actually, access token is an object, maybe it's failing to serialize, so just grab the string and save it?

Comment: With $_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
print_r($_SESSION['fb_access_token']); not show nothing. How can try grab the string and save it? thanks

Comment: did you not get it when you called `$accessToken->getValue()` previously?

Comment: if I get this $accessToken->getValue() and assign this to var session I get the same error. I don't know this. But I can print in the next php, and this show  [oauth_token] => ,  [oauth_token_secret] => ...

Comment: What about putting a random string on $_SESSION['fb_access_token'] and seeing if that survives to the next page? That way you can rule out the FB SDK and maybe see if the issue is somewhere else in your site.